# Webscraping emedded link contents in a url

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to scrape a website on product reviews and can't assign more than one url to a variable. Basically, I need to scrape urls in a url of specific content.

I have the parent url, and three linked pages to scrape product details like reviews, stars, ect. When passing more than one url to the assigned variable, a "connection adapter error" throws. I've also attempted to just compile, or copy the same code three times with no avail.

```
import requests as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url1 = 'http://drd.ba.ttu.edu/isqs6339/imbadproducts/'

filepath = 'dataout.csv'

res = r.get(url1)

res.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'lxml')

results = soup.find("a")
    print(results)

print(results['href'])

results = soup.find_all("a")

for l in results:
    print(l['href'])

for l in results:
    print(l.text)

print(res.headers)

product_result = soup.find_all('a')
for pr in product_result:
    print(pr)

search_results = soup.find('div', attrs={'id' : 'searchresults'})

product_result = search_results.find_all('a')
for pr in product_result:
    print(pr)
```

So I provided one link, but have three embedded links and different tags to scrape. I've never been able to get past the connection adapter error.

Comment: The original code is much longer with a write code to a csv file, but I had to remove because stackoverflow wouldn't let me post.

Comment: Show your expected result?

Comment: format the code

Comment: your code doesn't produce that error for me. Post enough code to demonstrate the problem. See [mcve].

Comment: The problem is assigning more than 1 link to the URL variable. Spyder/anaconda will show the "connection adapters" error and I can't effectively scrape the data specified in the request function. To iterate, I need to scrape three subpages in the main page/url. Can someone help with a functional example?